# Custom validation rule for tild and tilt character in PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need a good validation for tild(~) and tilt(`) character in PHP and Jquery.
Here is the Jquery validation what i have made.

```
$.validator.addMethod("validSMS", function(value, element) {
    if (value.indexOf('~') === -1 || value.indexOf('`') === -1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}, "Tild and tilt Character is not allowed");
```

But I need another good method for this validation in Jquery and in PHP also.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your validation in jQuery

Comment: Can u give the PHP validation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the php version, using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strrpos.php)

```
if (strrpos($mystring, "~") === false && strrpos($mystring, "`") === false ) { 
    // $mystring has no tild(~) and tilt(`) chars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what can be done with javascript. you can change condition as per your requirement.

```
<script language=javascript>
  var txt='jayd~ev';

  var re1='.*?';    // Non-greedy match on filler
  var re2='(~)';    // Any Single Character 1

  var p = new RegExp(re1+re2,["i"]);
  var m = p.exec(txt);
  if (m != null)
  {
      var c1=m[1];
      document.write("("+c1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"\n");
  }
</script>
```